# IE img tag failing but same image downloads ok

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I'm struggling with what feels like a recent issue to my private php CMS when delivering images. I feel (but can't confirm) that this was working a few days ago, but doesn't now (note I recall a large Windows update between then and now).

When I run something like the following HTML:

```
<IMG BORDER=1 SRC='https://my....site.com/myPHPDocument.php?d=23362'>
<BR>(<a href='https://my....site.com/myPHPDocument.php?d=23362'>Click here to see full size</a>)
```

then in IE I get the [X] image error icon, BUT when I run Chrome for the same page then I see my images ok

The other strange thing here is that when I look at other images from my site in IE then not everything fails in the  tags... some are ok... so it's not like the rendering code is completely wrong.

The PHP used to deliver the image is :

```
header("Pragma: ");
header("Content-type:".$extn);
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filenm));
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$externalNm");
if ( file_exists($filenm) ) {
    $bufferlength = 65536; 
    $fp = fopen($filenm, "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) 
    { 
        $buffer = fread($fp, $bufferlength);
        echo $buffer;
        flush();
    }
    fclose($fp); 
}
flush();
die();
```

I've tried this on IE9, 10 and 11 and they all show the [X]. Is it possible IE has tightened something that used to work 100% and now I find only works 30% of the time? Am I missing something in my headers (or something else)?

Comment: Are you showing the full `img` HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are `jpeg`, Internet explorer uses the mime type `image/pjpeg`. You use `pjpeg` for IE and `jpeg` for other browsers.

```
header("Content-Type: image/pjpeg");
```

Comment: Both callback and Alan above were correct - it was my header("Content-type:".$extn); which was using the wrong $extn value (it was showing "Content-type:application/octet-stream" instead of "Content-type:image/x-png" (for my png file). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start your investigation by removing the browser from the equation.  The `curl` command line program is an excellent resource for debugging these sorts of questions.  First, you can use it to look at the headers you're actually returning by using the `-I` option

```
curl -I https://my....site.com/myPHPDocument.php?d=23362
```

Then, you can use it to download the actual file and examine what's being downloaded.

```
curl https://my....site.com/myPHPDocument.php?d=23362 > file.png
```

Two quick guesses here

1. If you open `file.png` you'll see some PHP errors, or maybe an HTML page that renders an img tag (i.e. not a pure binary image)
2. Your `Content-Type` is incorrect.